# error Trying to get property of non-object in Laravel 5 with relation and scope

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm working in Laravel 5. My situation is the next: I have a table *USERS* and a table *PROFILES* the have a relation 1:1. So I have in the model *users* a method called profile like this:

```
public function profile(){      
        return $this->belongsTo('App\models\Profile','profile_id');
    }
```

Also I have a method *scopeData* where I want to filter what users have *identity_doc* equal as *data*:

```
public function scopeData($query,$data){
        $profile=$this->profile;
        $query->where($profile->identity_doc,$data);
    }
```

in the user controller I use the scope function in this line:

```
$students= Users::data($request->get('data'))->where('rol','=','Student')->get();
```

but, when I runned it I have this error: **Trying to get property of non-object**
so, why it happens? the profile method works fine in others functions, but no here, I get:

```
**array('query' => object(Builder), 'data' => 'example', 'profile' => null))**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my memory of Eloquent ORM serves me right, when you're using the scope it's adding to the query, meaning you're in the process of building the query and you haven't actually queried the database yet. However, the relationships (e.g. `->belongsTo(...)`) seem to work on instantiated objects - i.e. they work *after* you have finished getting them from the database.

So at that time of your scope your user does not actually exist yet. `$this` is not the user in your scope, and so `$this->profile` returns nothing - the query has not been run yet so it has no users, and so can have no profiles either. So then because `$profile` is null, accessing `$profile->indentity_doc` will cause that error you got.

Comment: ok, I understand, I though the same but I wasn't sure. Thank you man! so, exists a way to deal with situations like this? how I use the relations inside a scope?

Comment: Well eager loading is probably one part of your solution: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading.
e.g. Users::with('profile') - that at least gets you somewhere. I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to achieve with the ->identity_doc part. Could you explain more please?

Comment: sure, the thing is that I have a table in a view, and there I show some data of the user profile like name, identity doc,phone number,etc. But I have an _input text_ where the user can introduce some value and find the registers that coincide, he can find for number of passport or identity card. and then with that _data_ I trying to filter the registers and show the result to the user

Comment: Perhaps don't worry about using the scope and try something like this:
$students= Users::where('rol', '=', 'Student')->whereHas('profile', function($query) use ($data)
{
    $query->where('identity_doc', '=', $data);

})->get();

Ref: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations

Comment: I tried it, it gives me 0 rows as result. I also make some investigation and manipulated it too, so I noticed that the second query (the one that is inside the function makes the query return 0 rows)